# number series equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So we got the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}$$

and we gotta transform it into
$$3-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}$$

This is just a step from a larger solution that im trying to work through. But Ive been struggling with this step for days now and I cant seem to get through it. I think we somehow use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)} =\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} $$ but other than that i dont know

Answer (score 1):

You can use this decomposition $$\dfrac 1{k(k+1)(k+1)!}=\left(\dfrac 1{k\cdot k!}-\dfrac 1{(k+1)(k+1)!}\right)-\dfrac 1{(k+1)!}$$

There is a telescopic sum in parenthesis and the last term sums up to $\sum \frac 1{k!}$ after reindexing.

Just deal with indices at extremities to get the $3$ and $\frac 1{(n+1)(n+1)!}$ values.

Comment: Okay, this is really helpful. I split the sum into two, the telescopic sum and the other, and i tried to reduce the telscopic sum. I got $$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}$$ which is helpful for finding the last term, but i dont know how to get the 3

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac 1{(k+1)!}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac 1{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac 1{k!}-\frac 1{0!}-\frac 1{1!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac 1{k!}-2$

Answer (score 0):

I think a proof by math induction would be easier. Here's how to do it:

We need to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}=3-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $n=1$, LHS $=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and RHS $=\dfrac{1}{4}$, so condition is true for $n=1$.

Assume true for $n=m$. Consider $n=m+1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}+\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(m+1)(m+1)!}+\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{(m+2)^2}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}+\dfrac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{(m+2)^2-1}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{m^2+4m+3}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{(m+1)(m+3)}{(m+1)(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{m+3}{(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{(m+2)+1}{(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{m+2}{(m+2)(m+2)!}-\frac{1}{(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(m+2)!}-\frac{1}{(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{m+2}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(m+2)(m+2)!}$$
$$=3-\sum_{k=0}^{(m+1)+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{((m+1)+1)((m+1)+1)!}$$
Therefore, the condition is true for $n=m+1$ if true for $n=m$, and by math induction, true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$3 - \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac1{k!} = 1 - \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac 1{k!} = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(k+1)!}$$

So your identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}=3-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}$$

is equivalent to

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(k+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}$$

We have

$$\frac1{(k+1)!} + \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} = \frac {k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}$$

and, "coincidentally":

$$\frac1{k(k!)} - \frac1{(k+1)(k+1)!} = \frac {(k+1)^2-k}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}= \frac {k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}$$

Therefore we can calculate the telescoping sum:

\begin{align}
&\quad\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(k+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{k(k!)} - \frac1{(k+1)(k+1)!}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}
\end{align}

as desired.